# Sharepoint modal window not shown when no permissions to at least one in the library

Tags: sharepoint, permissions, modal-dialog, sharepoint-2013

I have a sharepoint 2013 farm solution with event receiver on Item Added (synchronously triggered) and when user uploads a file: permissions are broken, deleted and added again.

There are 3 groups: Visible, Edit and Hidden. 
When file is added as Edit or Visible group everything works fine, permissions are broken, added for Visible and Edit and modal window to input Required fields is shown. But when adding as Hidden group which cannot see the confidential files, permissions are added (Visible, Edit, Hidden) but the file is added and modal is not shown anymore. I can recreate such behaviour when I delete permissions for any group.

I tought it is sharepoint default behaviour but I have recreated this sittuation on a standard library and set same permissions with UI and modal is shown normally as it should.

Code of event:

```
  public override void ItemAdded(SPItemEventProperties properties)
    {
        base.ItemAdded(properties);

        var confidentialField = properties.List.Fields.TryGetFieldByStaticName(Consts.ConfidentialColumnName);
        var confidentialVisibleGroup = getGroup(properties.List, confidentialField, Consts.ConfidentialVisibleGroupName);
        var confidentialHiddenGroup = getGroup(properties.List, confidentialField, Consts.ConfidentialHiddenGroupName);
        var confidentialEditGroup = getGroup(properties.List, confidentialField, Consts.ConfidentialEditGroupName);

        using (var scope = new DisabledItemEventsScope())
        {
            properties.ListItem.File.CheckIn("test"); //need to check in the file because it won't exist when getting it with ID in elevated. it is checked out by default
            SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate ()
            {

                setPermissions(properties, confidentialVisibleGroup, confidentialHiddenGroup, confidentialEditGroup,
                    confidentialField.InternalName);


            });
            properties.ListItem.File.CheckOut(); // no matter if the file is checked out or not modal not shown
        }
    }

    private static void setPermissions(SPItemEventProperties properties, SPGroup confidentialVisibleGroup,
        SPGroup confidentialHiddenGroup, SPGroup confidentialEditGroup, string confidentialFieldInternalName)
    {
        try
        {
            using (var site = new SPSite(properties.SiteId))
            {
                using (var web = site.OpenWeb(properties.RelativeWebUrl))
                {
                    web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;

                    var list = web.Lists[properties.List.ID];
                    var listItem = list.GetItemById(properties.ListItemId);
                    listItem.BreakRoleInheritance(false);

                    //add 2 permission groups
                    var roleAssignment = new SPRoleAssignment(confidentialEditGroup);
                    roleAssignment.RoleDefinitionBindings.Add(
                        properties.Web.RoleDefinitions.GetByType(SPRoleType.Contributor));
                    listItem.RoleAssignments.Add(roleAssignment);

                    roleAssignment = new SPRoleAssignment(confidentialVisibleGroup);
                    roleAssignment.RoleDefinitionBindings.Add(
                        properties.Web.RoleDefinitions.GetByType(SPRoleType.Contributor));
                    listItem.RoleAssignments.Add(roleAssignment);

                    //add hidden group with no permissions to all files on library
                    roleAssignment = new SPRoleAssignment(confidentialHiddenGroup);
                        roleAssignment.RoleDefinitionBindings.Add(
                            properties.Web.RoleDefinitions.GetByType(SPRoleType.Contributor));
                        listItem.RoleAssignments.Add(roleAssignment);

                    listItem.SystemUpdate();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Logger.GetLogger().WriteLog("Exception while setting permissions to confidential item", e);
        }
    }
```